# Is it possible to loop in TiKz to draw the same shape on different coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

Is it possible in Tikz to draw the same shape over and over again by just changing the x and y coordinates periodically in a for loop or something like that? I have a particular array of triangles which I have generated in some other computer language and I have added a snapshot to illustrate my point. I have just started using Tikz and I find it a bit complex at the moment.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @PaulGaborit How can I do so? Is there any example you have at hand?

Comment: Search questions and answers about [TikZ and pic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tikz+pic)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example for loops.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {triangle/.pic =
    {\path[fill] (0,0) -- (-0.3,0.8) -- (0.3,0.8) -- cycle;
    }
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y in {0, ..., 7}
    {\foreach \x in {-\y, ..., \y}
       \pic at (\x,-\y) {triangle};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer as far as I understood, \tikzset command sets the vertices in relative coordinates, am I correct?

Comment: @Vesnog No, this is not related to `\tikzset`, which just sets tikz parameters. But `pic`s (small pictures to be used in another picture) have the property that  their coordinate `(0,0)` refers to the last coordinate having been mentioned where the `pic` is used. So the coordinates in a pic are relative to this external point.